# accuracy drops around 10% after exporting from pytorch to ONNX

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, onnx

I've been training an efficientnetV2 network using [this repository](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models).

The train process goes well and I reach around 93-95% validation accuracy. After that I run an inference process over a set test which contains new images with an acceptable accuracy, around 88% (for example).

After I check if the model works fine on pytorch I need to convert it to ONNX and then to a tensorrt engine. I have a script to run inference with an ONNX model to check if I'm having some problems with the conversion process.

I'm using this code to convert the model:

```
import torch
from timm.models import create_model
import os
# create model
base_model = create_model(
    model_arch,
    num_classes=num_classes,
    in_chans=3,
    checkpoint_path=model_path)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    base_model,
    torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)

model.cpu()
model.eval()

dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=True)

torch.onnx.export(model,
                  dummy_input,
                  model_export,
                  verbose=False,
                  export_params=True,
                  do_constant_folding=True
                  )
```

I've tried several tutorials like [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/best-practices-for-neural-network-exports-to-onnx-99f23006c1d5) but unfortunately I'm getting the same result.

I've tried different onset combinations, with and without do_constant_folding, I've even trained another model with parameter called 'exportable', which is a bool and tells the train script if the model is exportable or not (is an experimental feature according to repository's documentation).

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the preprocessing steps the same for both the torch evaluation and the ONNX evaluation?

Comment: Do you use tf_efficientnetv2 model? If so, as timm's creator said "the tf_ variants it's likely the same padding hack that's added to make pytorch models compat with the tensorflow padding. The few models I've trained myself without the tf_ prefix shouldn't have that problem. If they do it's likely an onnx / pytorch compat issue as those crop up from time to time."